# Repeated regex pattern

Tags: regex

I'm in need to make a regex to match some String formats, I'm not really good to Regex,  that is why I'm asking for your help.

I receive a bank of Strings, they start with the following format:

Examples: `"1ASF1-1-A42-A_4-214A-GarbageText", "DI-21f-112rf-A-214_124_12412A_GarbageText", "312c_12412_1241-12rf-001-GarbageText"`

An AlfaNumeric that has from 1 - 20 characters + ( - or _) repeated any times (can't know how many repeatings) Then it has some garbage text.

How can I make a regex to find if the String starts with the pattern I want? I think It would be something like:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}[_-]+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What've you've written means the string must end in one-to-many `-` or `_` characters, not have just one, then "garbage text".

You need to group the repeated pattern.

Then if you have "garbage text", then you can use `.+`

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}[_-])+.+
```

But this will include spaces and any other symbols rather than just `[a-zA-Z0-9]`... `\w+` might be "safer"

Comment: `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}[_-])+.+` just to save some buffer space :)

Comment: Thanks dude, I forgot to ask, Do you know How can I cut the part of the string that matches the regex and exclude the garbage?

Comment: Well, the whole string needs to "match" ... In Java, you can use `Matcher` class to get the data _within the parenthesis_

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the whole string, you can start with the pattern 1-20 chars, and then optionally repeat `-` or `_` followed by again the pattern 1-20 chars.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4eOZam/1)

If you want the match until the last occurrence of `-` or `_` when there are not consecutive dashes or underscores like `--`:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})*[_-]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5M0oGQ/1)

If they can also be mixed:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*[-_])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HGfh8w/1)